# Getting selected option in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am generating a thumbnail list of photos (using ng-repeat), and under each one of these photos I have two buttons, one to view more details and another to purchase.

I am finding a problem how to map the buttons.  Basically I want that when a user clicks on the purchase button underneath Photo A, in the booking form (which is a different view), he/she will see the details pertaining to Photo A, rather than having the user select the photo again from some drop down.  The list of photos is coming from a JSON string.

Mainly the difficulty I am finding is how to pass the details of which button was clicked to the booking view so that I would be able to display the details of the selected photo immediately.

I am new to AngularJS and am not sure if there is a simple way that can be done.

My HTML is this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 ng-scope" ng-repeat="photo in photos">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="{{photo.thumbnail}}" alt="{{photo.title}}">
  <div class="caption">
    <h4 class="ng-binding">{{photo.title}}</h4>
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Photographer</button><br ><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Purchase</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular JS:

App JS

```
angular
.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

        .state('photos', {
            url: '/photos',
            templateUrl: 'templates/photos.html',
            controller: 'photosCtrl',
            resolve: { photos: ['$http', function($http){
                    return $http.get('api/photos.json').then(function(response){
                        return response.data;
                    });
            }]}
        })      

}]);
```

photosCtrl JS:

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('photosCtrl', ['$scope', 'photos', function($scope, photos) {
    $scope.photos = photos;
}]);
```

Comment: share the HTML & JS code / share it in JsFiddler

Comment: not clear your question ..

Comment: @NitishKumar basically I have am generating a dynamic list of thumbnails of photos and each thumbnail has 2 buttons underneath it, one to view information about the photographer and another to purchase the photo.  My difficulty is how to link the buttons so that when the user clicks on the purchase button of Photo A, for example, he will be taken to the purchase form (which is a different view) and have the details of Photo A displayed there already, without the user having to reselect the photo from some combo-box.

Comment: @NitishKumar in simple words I am not sure how to pass the selected index kind of, so that I would re-display the information of the selected photo in the purchase form state/view

Comment: there are two other controller for details of photo and purchase ?

Comment: yes ultimately there will be 2 controllers, one for each

Comment: Maybe you need to use `$index` inside `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `ngClick` directive is a good idea as @Ashesh suggested

Assuming the JSON containing your photos comes with a bunch of photo object, I'd rather add two functions to the scope of `photosCtrl` like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('photosCtrl', ['$scope', 'photos', function($scope, photos) {
    $scope.photos = photos;

    $scope.showDetailsOf = function(photo) {
        // photo argument is the actual object of which 'details' button was pressed
        // coming from the ngRepeat in your template example
        console.log('show details of ' + photo.title);
    }

    $scope.purchase = function(photo) {
        // same as above
        console.log('purchase ' + photo.title);
    }
}]);
```

The template should look like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showDetailsOf(photo)">Details</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="purchase(photo)">Purchase</button>
```

Furthermore you can factor this logic out to e.g. a `photoService` so that your controller won't contain business logic which is always preferable as both of your controller and the service can be covered by tests more easily, because you decouple them. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngClick`:

```
<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="photo.showPhotographer()">Photographer</button><br ><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="photo.buy()">Purchase</button></p>
```

And ofcourse, `photo.showPhotographer()` etc. can do what you like them to do:

```
function Photo() { // the photo object
    this.buy() {
        // api call to buy with the id of the photo or window.navigate('buy_url?id=' + this.id), etc.
    }
}
```